# Multidimensional Vector in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, actionscript-3, vector

How can I initialise two-dimentional typed Vector is AS3?

Now I can get working only this:

```
private var _mainArray : Array = new Array( MyConst.DIMENTION );

public function MyArray() 
{
        for ( var i : int = 0; i < MyConst.DIMENTION; i++ ) {
        _mainArray[ i ] = new Vector.<int>( MyConst.DIMENTION );
    }
}

...
_mainArray[ i ][ j ] = 0;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have is an Array of Vector of int. What you want is a Vector of Vector of int.

So your "outer" Vector has to declare that contains elements of type `Vector.<int>`

Something like this (of course you can use a for loop):

```
    var v:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>(2);
    v[0] = new Vector.<int>(2);
    v[1] = new Vector.<int>(2);
    v[0][0] = 0;
    v[0][1] = 1;
    v[1][0] = 2;
    v[1][1] = 3;
    trace(v);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private var _labelsRefs:Vector.<Vector.<Object>> = new Vector.<Vector.<Object>>( );
private var _labelsFrRefs:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>( );
private var _labelsEnRefs:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>( );
_labelsRefs [ _labelsRefs.length ] = _labelsFrRefs;
_labelsRefs [ _labelsRefs.length ] = _labelsEnRefs;
```

You can add 10 additional items if you want

```
_labelsFrRefs [ _labelsFrRefs.length ] = [ _label.@key, _label.@xml ];
```

Then you can search in the _labelsRefs:Vector

```
public function searchKeyXml ( langue:String, key:String, val:int ):String
searchKeyXml ( "fr", "three", 1 ); medias/xmls/fr/homepage1.xml
searchKeyXml ( "en", "three", 1 ); medias/xmls/en/homepage1.xml
```